# simple php problem

Tags: php, syntax, cookies

OK, so here's the snippet:

```
                // start rememberMe
    $cookie_name = 'db_auth';

    $cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 30); // 30 days

    // check to see if user checked box
    if ($remember == 1) {
setcookie ($cookie_name, 'username='.$username., time() + $cookie_time);
    }
```

For some reason it breaks and I can't see why. It is part of a larger function which works fine when I comment this snippet out. Any ideas?

Comment: The function that this is part of is one of a list of functions that I've declared in an external file that is then included in pages that need those functions. When I say break I mean that it makes everything stop working - even if I haven't called that particular function. That's why I assumed it was a syntax thing that I couldn't see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra dot after "$username" in the second last line.

Comment: Hang on! Tried it again - and works perfectly. Not sure what I did first time i tried it.... :)

Comment: php -l will syntax-check a file

Answer (score 0):

try putting parentheses around your arguments for setcookie?

like this:

```
setcookie ($cookie_name, ('username='.$username), (time() + $cookie_time));
```

untested, but maybe the plus sign is causing your issue?

This is also assuming that the rest of your code is ok. Usually php throws errors, so if you're getting a blank page, the first place I would look is your page source.

Comment: alas not. Just tried it. I also tried putting double inverted commas around the username bit.